# Unhandled exception at 0x76fe15de in GLut.h/ osfinfo.c/ dbgheap.c/ mlock.c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, opengl, unhandled-exception

Using Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit with Visual Studio 2010 Professional on HP Pavilion g6. Code is written in C/C++.

Links:

```
Additional Include Directories: N/A - Everything needed is in the VS2010 Include Directory
Additional Library Directories: N/A - Everything needed is in the VS2010 Lib Directory
Additional Dependencies (Debug Mode): glew32d.lib;glew32sd.lib;glu32.lib;opengl32.lib;gdi32.lib;winmm.lib;user32.lib;
```

Code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <GL\glew.h>
    #include <GL\wglew.h> 
    #include <GL\glut1.h>
    #include <GL\glext.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);

        const unsigned char * version ;
        version = (const unsigned char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION);
        printf ("My OpenGL version is %s\n", version); //Comment this out for error in Glut, leave for the other 2 errors

        // Obtain a buffer identifier from OpenGL
        GLuint bufferID = 0;
        glGenBuffers( 1, &bufferID ); //Comment out for no reported errors

        return 0;
    }
```

Reported Errors:

```
glut.h:
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x76fe15de in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Error occurs on line 486 - static void APIENTRY glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK(int *argcp, char **argv) { __glutInitWithExit(argcp, argv, exit); }

osfinfo.c:
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x76fe15de in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Error occurs on line 467 - return retval; // in function, int __cdecl __lock_fhandle (int fh)

dbgheap.c:
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x76fe15de in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Error occurs on line 504 - __finally {_munlock(_HEAP_LOCK);}

mlock.c:
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x76fe15de in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Error occurs on line 375 - } // end of function, void __cdecl _unlock (int locknum)
```

Other Noticed Symptoms:

- Crash alternates between osfinfo.c, dbgheap.c and mlock.c when printf command **ISN'T** commented out
- Only crashes on glut.h when printf **IS** commented out
- When glGenBuffers is commented out, there are no unhandled exception errors - the program does not crash
- Output of printf statement is: My OpenGL version is (null) - occurs irrespective of whether the program crashes or not

I'm completely stumped on this one, there appears to be literally nothing on the internet to help me out. I even focused on trying to solve the "OpenGL version = null" problem first, but I came out empty handed as I either followed the advice on [this website](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/149571-glGetString%28GL_VERSION%29-return-Null-argh-!) incorrectly (not having a good enough understanding about OpenGL rendering contexts) or that problem is a symptom of the 0xC0000005 error.

---

EDIT: As this problem seems to be caused by multiple problems I have decided to put an updated version of my code and the corresponding error I am getting from it. Thank you for helping me so far, but glGenBuffers just seems to hold a grudge on me or something.

NEW Code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <cmath>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <GL\glew.h>
    #include <GL\glut.h>
    #include <GL\glext.h>
    #include <GL\wglew.h>
    #include <GL\wglext.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>

    using namespace std;
    void drawScene();
    void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
    void handleMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
    void handleResize(int w, int h);
    void update(int value);
    void printw (float x, float y, float z, char* format, ...);

    GLvoid *font_style = GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH); 
        glutInitWindowSize(960, 460);
        glutCreateWindow("Piece of Shit");
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
        glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
        glutMouseFunc(handleMouse);
        glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
        glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }

    void drawScene()
    {
        double x, z;
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
        GLuint bufferID[1];

        GLenum err = glewInit();
        if (GLEW_OK != err)
            printw(-6, 1.5, -10, "Fail: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        printw(-3, 0.3, -10, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));
        glGenBuffers( 1, &bufferID[0] ); // comment out and you have no problems********************************
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }

    void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
    {
    }

    void handleMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
    {
    }

    void handleResize(int w, int h)
    {   
        glViewport(0,0,w,h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45.0, (double)w / (double)h, 1.0, 200.0);
    }

    void update(int value)
    {
        glutPostRedisplay();
        glutTimerFunc(20, update, 0);
    }

    void printw (float x, float y, float z, char* format, ...)
    {
        va_list args;   //  Variable argument list
        int len;        // String length
        int i;          //  Iterator
        char* text;     // Text

        //  Initialize a variable argument list
        va_start(args, format);

        //  Return the number of characters in the string referenced the list of arguments.
        // _vscprintf doesn't count terminating '\0' (that's why +1)
        len = _vscprintf(format, args) + 1;

        //  Allocate memory for a string of the specified size
        text = (char*) malloc (len * sizeof(char));

        //  Write formatted output using a pointer to the list of arguments
        vsprintf_s(text, len, format, args);

        //  End using variable argument list
        va_end(args);

        //  Specify the raster position for pixel operations.
        glRasterPos3f (x, y, z);

        //  Draw the characters one by one
        for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
        glutBitmapCharacter(font_style, text[i]);

        //  Free the allocated memory for the string
        free(text);
    }
```

Error: gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers

Comment: `0x76fe15de` is an address, and the error code is `0xC0000005`.

Comment: By the way, the first thing you should do when getting crashes, is to run the program in the debugger. Not only will it help you find the locations of the crashes, it will also let you examine variables to see that might have caused the crash.

Comment: That's what I thought I had done, which is where I got the "Error occurs at" information from. I clicked on the "play" button that states "start debugging". Is there an alternate method I could use as well? (I have tried F11 (step through code) but due to the printf command it takes forever to get there. When the printf command is gone however, it pretty much just goes straight to the error I mentioned in the glut.h file.)

Comment: When searching for the 0xC0000005 error, I found information stating the error may be caused by faulty memory. I have run the "Windows Memory Diagnostic" tool to clarify this is not the case. There were no errors so it is definitely a problem with the code.

Comment: Have you tried calling `glGetError` after every OpenGL call?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on how to use glGetError. When I used 'printf("x%/n",glGetError)' it returned with the value 5a0d3a23.

Comment: `glGetError` is a function, see [this link](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml).

Comment: OK, the error I'm getting is GL_INVALID_OPERATION. How should I go about debugging it when it's the only thing in my code? (I commented everything else out)

Comment: You can only call glGetError after you have a valid context setup (from glutInit I believe).

Comment: I still get the same error whether glutInit is there or not.
I get the feeling that it might just be something really simple that I'm missing within the properties of the program. I had a problem with OpenCV at one point that required me to change some odd settings I hadn't expected to change. Unfortunately I don't have anybody with a fully functioning version of OpenGL with GLew around to compare settings with.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that glGenBuffers isn't defined.  I noticed that you're trying to use GLEW to solve that.  You'll need to do a bit more to set up GLEW, as you guessed.  You need a call to glewInit.  My code looks something like (simplified for clarity):

```
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (err != GLEW_OK) {
    string error = "GLEW extension loading failed: "+string((char*)glewGetErrorString(err));
    printf("%s\n",error); getchar();
}
```

Add that code after you set up a context (i.e., after glutInit).  I don't know about your OpenGL version being NULL--the last time I encountered that was on a pretty old card--probably an integrated chipset.  If that's your case, there's probably nothing to worry about.

Comment: You can not use GL functions before opening actual window - glutInit doesn't create GL context. That's why version is NULL.

Comment: After looking on the internet yesterday I confirmed that I need to do more than just use glutInit() to set up a context for OpenGL, however, when I did this I could no longer print anything to the console window, meaning I'm stuck if I want to get any sensible info out. I did read somewhere (at about 1am...) about there being a command to draw the text into the OpenGL window to solve this, but I've forgotten where I saw this now. Is this the case? If so, what's the function I need to use?

Comment: A friend of mine, whom is also just starting to use OpenGL, has created a program that works for OpenGL 1.1 (aka, no functions from versions greater than 1.1), and from this I have definitely initialized OpenGL. I have proven this to myself by using the code from this website that allows to to draw text into the GL image box. GL version - 3.0.0 Build 8.15.10.2353; Going back to the original problem with glGenBuffers, I now get "First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in gl_crap3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation", but this time in mlock.c only.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko: can't believe I missed that.  Anyway--@JamesPerrin, did you add the GLEW code above after setting up your context?

Comment: @Ian Mallett, I've put an updated version of my code in the main question section. I played with it all of yesterday but I couldn't find the "missing link" for glGenBuffers. I've tested glut and glew and they are both fully functional, and I have glut32.lib & glew32d.lib linked to it (have also tried with glew32sd.lib). I have also tried including them with #pragma, but the same LNK2001 error crops up all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everybody. After playing around with this for over a week now I believe that the problem may be the Visual Studio 2010 Compiler itself **09/08/2012**.

I will be trying Linux in an attempt to remedy my problem.

Comment: I added this comment to the original question. please remove this answer is its not a real answer